# datagrid.itemssource = e.Result doesn't work in mainpage - silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm creating a silverlight webapplication and i use linq to sql to bind my
sql database. This works. My problem now is, that when i try to save my data
in a datagrid or listbox, nothing happens (means no output).

here my code in wcf service file:

```
public List<mytable> get_info()
    {
        LinqMapInfoDataContext _context = new LinqMapInfoDataContext();
        var result = (from x in _context.mytable select x).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

in mainpage.xaml.cs

```
private void ser_client_get_infoCompleted(object sender, ServiceRefMapInfo.get_infoCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid1 = new DataGrid();
        grid1.ItemsSource = e.Result;                       
    }
```

Web.Config

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>

  <bindings>

    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="IncreasedTimeout"
               sendTimeout="00:25:00">
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>

  </bindings>



    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a DataGrid to hold the data but you are not adding to the LayoutRoot.

Move the creation of the DataGrid to the constructor of the page where you will need to add it to the page, or better still define it in the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid ..../>
</Grid>
```

(much simplified).

The next step is to check that the data is actually being returned to the client. Set a break point at:

```
grid1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
```

Try to view the value of e.Result in the debugger. This should display the list of items you want to display. However, your query is only evaluated at this point so if you are returning a lot of items this could take a very long time or even time out. If this is happening you need to increase the time out on the service call. In the first instance though edit the query on the server side so that it returns only a few 10's of items. This will allow you to verify that the data is being returned correctly.

To increase the timeout add this to the web.config file:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="IncreasedTimeout"
             sendTimeout="00:25:00">
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Another thing that's odd is that you are returning your data in a `List` rather than an `IQueryable`. With small amounts of data I don't think it should make any difference (given the code you've posted) but it's something else to try. However, if you are potentially returning large amounts of data you should look into it as it supports paging.

This allows you to control how much of your data gets returned in a single call. This speeds it up and reduces the memory footprint of your client (something else that can be going wrong). Then in the UI you display a page of data at a time and allow the user to navigate through this.

Comment: I added  <Datagrid> into the <Grid>, still not working. I dont get any error messages, but what i noticed is, that everything after grid1.ItemsSource = e.Result; will be ignored by the compiler.

Comment: Where in my web.config file do i have to implement that part of code? Edit: Before i tried to receive multiple information from my sql database, i had changed the code to get only one single information and i returned the value into a label. that worked.

Comment: @user2037740 - The fact you get one back would indicate that it's the timeout. It goes in the `bindings` section. I'll update the answer as well.

Comment: I added my web.config file in my first post. maybe you can find something there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I always rebuilt my solution after i changed anything in my linq2sql or Service files.
But that wasn't enough. I had to "right click" on my Service Reference in my solution folder and click on "actualize Service Reference". After that it worked fine.

Thanks for your help, ChrisF.